# Persistent web cache?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish

I'm building nginx cache on a development machine and try to copy the files to a server that has the same nginx cache settings. But nginx is not picking up my copied caches and overwrite my caches.

**Update #1:**

Testing the persistent cache in Varnish.

**Update #2:**

Persistent cache in Varnish is experimental and crashes. =(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `proxy_store` in Nginx instead of `proxy_cache`. While `proxy_cache` is under control of Nginx (so that your own files may interfere in some way), `proxy_store` is used to create mirrors. It's probably better fit for your needs.